# Fragment Refresh When Activity Textview Value changed

Tags: android, fragment

I want to know how can i update fragment recyclerview data of fragment when user change the City name.

Suppose I have one textview(which holds the city name) in my activity I'm sending the value of textview to fragment using intent, for the first time its works fine but when the value of textview changed the fragment recyclerview data wont update according to the textview value(i.e city name).

For better understanding I'm giving an example.

Suppose in my textview city name is set to MUMBAI for the first time the data is fetching perfectly fine from database to recyclerview but when the texview value changed to suppose Pune then the fragment recyclerview data wont get update according to city name.

The working is same as OLX fetching result according to city names.

thank you in advance and hope I explain properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a textChangeListener to the textView in the activity, and create a method inside the fragment for receiving the data and updating the fragment.

Something like this perhaps:

```
    Fragment frag = ...
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            frag.updateSomething("some argument");   
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **UpdateCallback** interface:

```
interface UpdateCallback {
   public void update(String s);
}
```

Implement **update** method on fragment:

```
class MyFragment Extends Fragment implements UpdateCallback {
     @Override
     public void update(String s){
         ...
     }
}
```

Finally call method in **afterTextChanged()**:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        myFragment.update(s);   
    }
});
```